# UINavigationController Custom Interactive Transition nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am implementing a custom interactive navigation controller transition to "push" a new view controller by panning downwards on the navigation controller's view.

Everything works great, except in situations where (in efforts to break the app), I pan down again on the navigation controller's view to initiate a new interactive pushing of a view controller.  If I do it quick enough after just finishing the previous one, I get a warning

**"nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"**

And eventually as I continue to play with the app, I will get:

**Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.**

I understand the for whatever reason, the context is not back in correct state, and there is something weird probably happening in the viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear methods in the pushed controller, but I'm not able to narrow down where exactly to stop the pushing of a new view controller before making sure the last view controller has FOR SURE finished being pushed.

I've played around with transition coordinator's notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock, by disabling the pan gesture until this block gets called, but this has not helped me.

I've searched on SO for these warnings, but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation - whereas I feel like its something to do with the context not being managed properly.

Here is the code I'm using:

I set a delegate to handle the pan gesture's begin state by pushing the view controller onto the stack:

`Application.h`

```
-(void)transitionManagerDidBeginDraggingDown:(TransitionManager *)transitionManager{
    MenuViewController *menu = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];
}
```

This method below is what initiates the delegate's pushing of the view controller onto the stack:

`TransitionManage.h`

```
- (void)panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture{

    UIViewController *toVc = [self.context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromVc = [self.context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{

            if (self.interactiveTransitionUnderway == NO) {
                self.interactive = YES;

                CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:gesture.view];
                if (velocity.y < 0) {           // we are pulling upwards on the visible view
                    self.presenting = YES;
                    [self.delegate transitionManagerDidBeginDraggingUp:self];
                }
                else{           // we are pulling downwards on the visible view
                    self.presenting = NO;
                    [self.delegate transitionManagerDidBeginDraggingDown:self];
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            CGPoint touchLocation = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
            CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];

            CGPoint updatedCenter = CGPointMake(self.beginPoint.x, self.beginPoint.y + translation.y);
            toVc.view.center = updatedCenter;
            CGFloat d = fabs(touchLocation.y / CGRectGetHeight(self.parentViewController.view.bounds)) ;

            [self.context updateInteractiveTransition:d];
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:{

            CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:gesture.view];
            CGRect frame;

            if (velocity.y < 0)
                frame = CGRectMake(0, -toVc.view.frame.size.height, toVc.view.frame.size.width, toVc.view.frame.size.height); // pulling up
            else
                frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, toVc.view.frame.size.width, toVc.view.frame.size.height);                            // pulling down

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.8 initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                                    toVc.view.frame = frame;
                                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    if (velocity.y < 0){
                                        [self cancelInteractiveTransition];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        [self finishInteractiveTransition];
                                        UIView *snapshotView = [fromVc.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
                                        [toVc.view addSubview:snapshotView];
                                        [toVc.view sendSubviewToBack:snapshotView];
                                    }
                                    [self completeTransition];
                                }];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)completeTransition{
    BOOL finished = ![self.context transitionWasCancelled];
    [self.context completeTransition:finished];
}


- (void)animationEnded:(BOOL)transitionCompleted {
    // Reset to our default state
    self.interactive = NO;
    self.presenting = NO;
    self.context = nil;
    self.interactiveTransitionUnderway = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a full answer to your issue but at least you should prevent your code from pushing a new viewcontroller with animation before the previous view controller is fully pushed (animation finished).